# Use xargs on file or content that contains quotes/single quotes

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, xargs

I am having difficulty using xargs with files with `'`, is there a way to by pass this problem?

> $ find . | xargs -I FILE echo FILE
>
> xargs: unterminated quote

file name

> $ ls
>
> mike's sample 16

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `NUL` character to separate the file names:

```
$find . -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

Comment: what if i want to rename them like this `| xargs -I FILE mv FILE <new_name>`

Comment: @user2167582 if that's what you want to do, look into the `-exec` parameter of find , that's the preferred way. but if you must use xargs: `find . -print0 | xargs -0 -I FILE mv FILE newname`, but this will only work if find returns 1 file only.